# SqlException was caught -> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

Platform used: Visual studio 2010 and SQL server 2008 R2

I keep getting a null exception that says "Incorrect syntax near ')'." at the below highlighted point i.e at Reader part. Before this, the exception said a Reader is already open because I was using a nested Reader and was resolved with 'MultipleActiveResultSets=True' in connection string. Attached code snippet and error log too.

Can anybody help in resolving this?

```
SqlCommand cmdDetails8 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [sub].[szn_TimeCard_Week] WHERE     [szn_user_name] = @usrname AND [szn_start_date] = @strtdate) AND ([szn_thu] = 0)", conn);
cmdDetails8.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usrname", tymT.UserName);
cmdDetails8.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strtdate", strtDate);

using (SqlDataReader reader1 = cmdDetails8.ExecuteReader()) //  null exception point
{
    if (reader1.HasRows)
    {
        SqlCommand cmdDetails9 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [sub].[szn_TimeCard_Week] SET [szn_thu] =      
        @hrs  WHERE [szn_user_name] = @usrname AND [szn_start_date] =   
        @strtdate;", conn);
        cmdDetails9.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usrname", tymT.UserName);
        cmdDetails9.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strtdate", strtDate);
        cmdDetails9.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hrs", dayTotalHrs);
    }
    else 
    {
        SqlCommand cmdDetails9 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [sub].[szn_TimeCard_Week]   
        ([szn_user_name],[szn_start_date],[szn_thu]) VALUES (@usr_name,@strt_date,@hrs));",  
        conn);
        cmdDetails9.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usr_name", tymT.UserName);
        cmdDetails9.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strt_date", strtDate);
        cmdDetails9.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hrs", dayTotalHrs);
    }
    reader1.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem is, aptly, on the first line:

```
SELECT * FROM [sub].[szn_TimeCard_Week]
WHERE [szn_user_name] = @usrname AND [szn_start_date] = @strtdate)
                                                                 ^
```

You don't have an opening parenthesis meaning that the closing parenthesis is causing unbalance in the universe.

Your second problem is on the first line in your `else` block, which has a superfluous closing parenthesis:

```
INSERT INTO [sub].[szn_TimeCard_Week]   
    ([szn_user_name],[szn_start_date],[szn_thu])
VALUES
    (@usr_name,@strt_date,@hrs))
                               ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Initially, you should change this

```
"SELECT * FROM [sub].[szn_TimeCard_Week] 
 WHERE [szn_user_name] = @usrname AND [szn_start_date] = @strtdate) AND ([szn_thu] = 0)"
```

to this

```
"SELECT * FROM [sub].[szn_TimeCard_Week] 
 WHERE [szn_user_name] = @usrname AND [szn_start_date] = @strtdate AND ([szn_thu] = 0)"
```

You don't need the extra `)` next to `strtdate`.

Furthermore, you should change also this

```
VALUES (@usr_name,@strt_date,@hrs))
```

to

```
VALUES (@usr_name,@strt_date,@hrs)
```

You don't need there the extra `)`. It's a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

In this statement is the last `)` to much:

```
"INSERT INTO [sub].[szn_TimeCard_Week]   ([szn_user_name],[szn_start_date],[szn_thu]) VALUES (@usr_name,@strt_date,@hrs));
                                                                                                                        ^
```

Comment: Not the only problem as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The first sql query has erros write this:

```
   SELECT * FROM [sub].[szn_TimeCard_Week] WHERE     [szn_user_name] = @usrname AND [szn_start_date] = @strtdate AND ([szn_thu] = 0);
```

And in the last write this:

```
    INSERT INTO [sub].[szn_TimeCard_Week]   
    ([szn_user_name],[szn_start_date],[szn_thu]) VALUES (@usr_name,@strt_date,@hrs);
```

Answer (score 0):

This query in your code has issues with brackets. There is one additional closing barcket after start date parameter. You need to correct that by applying brackets as per your need.

```
SELECT * FROM [sub].[szn_TimeCard_Week] WHERE     [szn_user_name] = @usrname AND [szn_start_date] = @strtdate) AND ([szn_thu] = 0)
```